# How to restores files lost from application during upgrade of app

Tags: iphone, applications, data-recovery

I had a lot of important files on my iPhone in an app called Documents Mobile Office. 
During upgrade of the application, the upgrade failed & the application does not reload. Hence I can't access the files in the application (.doc, .csv etc).

As I thought all files would be auto uploaded to the "cloud" I did not back it up in iTunes.

I have a few of these files on my Google Dashboard which I have recovered, the rest I can't. How do I recover these lost files?

Please help.

Comment: I don't think Documents Mobile syncs with iCloud (at least not according to the description in the App Store) so it's either local or in Google Documents. But the documents should be in the iPhone backup in iTunes, try to restore from there.

Answer (score 1):

Your data should be recoverable!

1. Download and install [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) on your PC or Mac.
2. Connect your iPhone to your computer.
3. Open iExplorer.
4. Your iPhone should appear on the sidebar on the left; double-click on "Apps".
5. Find Documents Mobile in the list that opens.  Double-click on it.
6. You should see a folder inside Documents Mobile called "Documents".  Drag and drop it to your Desktop and iExplorer should copy the documents in Mobile Documents to your computer.